# Is including an iframe with a web extension considered remote code?

Tags: iframe, google-chrome-extension, add-on

While submitting an extension to the Chrome Store this question is asked regarding remote code:

> ("All JS, Wasm or CSS that are not part of the administration package
>   are remote code. This also includes references to external processes
>   in  tags, modules that refer to external personal and strings
>   determined via "eval ()".)

In the case of my extension I don't use eval(), or directly inject other scripts libraries, I just put an iframe that  will have its own libraries.

Should I report this behavior remote-code?

Code to add the data

```
const iframe = document.createElement('iframe')
iframe.src = `URL STRING`
iframe.id = 'Frame'

document.body.appendChild(style)
document.body.appendChild(iframe)
```

Comment: Without seeing the code/html all we can do is play a guessing game and this is definitely the wrong approach.

Comment: I updated the question with the code to append the iframe, but in this case I don't see it necessary, since is not a question of how I add it but if it is considered remote code the execution of the scripts inside the iframe.

Comment: This code is a generic example of adding an iframe but what are the actual URL types of the iframe and the resources? If the iframe is a chrome-extension:// URL but the libraries are not then this will be definitely considered remote code. Otherwise it depends. This is why it's important to provide a realistic [MCVE](/help/mcve).

Comment: @wOxxOm what if the iframe URL is external i.e.: `www.example.com`. Would that be considered "remotely executed code"?

Comment: I don't know, probably not. Try searching/asking in this [extensions forum](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-extensions) where the official representatives often answer questions. I think someone already asked about external iframes there.